# why does test command startswith fail (exit with 1)?

Tags: bash, shell, test

I have this test command:

```
test "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/teros/moodwire_demo" == ssh*; echo $?
```

why does it exit with 1? I am trying to see if the first string starts with the second string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` command in `bash` can't do that.  For strings, it only supports tests for equality, non-equality, and lexicographical ordering (see `help test` in `bash`).

You may however use

```
[[ "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/teros/moodwire_demo" == ssh* ]]
echo "$?"
```

This form of string matching is only done within `[[ ... ]]` in `bash`.

Without using `[[ ... ]]`:

```
expr "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/teros/moodwire_demo" : '^ssh' >/dev/null
echo "$?"
```

This uses the `expr` utility to match the (basic)  *regular expression* `^ssh` against the string.  Since `expr` is not a built-in utility, this would be ever so slightly slower than using `==` within `[[ ... ]]` in `bash`.

Comment: ughh I dislike having to use double brackets :(  I wonder if there is some way to get around it

Comment: @Alexander Mills If you don't like double brackets, you can use grep for simple regexp tests like this: `grep '^ssh' <<< 'ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/teros/moodwire_demo'; echo $?`